# Python method changing its own class

Tags: python, oop, selenium-webdriver

Using Python/Selenium, I have many page objects that will return each other when following a link. This works perfectly, but for convenience I would like to continually call methods on the same variable without reassigning it.

A toy example below:

```
class Foo(object):
    identity = 'foo'
    def __init__(self, key):
        self.key = key
    def change(self):
        return Bar(self.key)

class Bar(object):
    identity = 'bar'
    def __init__(self, key):
        self.key = key
    def change(self):
        return Blah(self.key)

class Blah(object):
    identity = 'blah'
    def __init__(self, key):
        self.key = key
    def change(self):
        return Foo(self.key)

x = Foo('somekey')
x.identity # > 'foo'
x.key # > 'somekey'
x = x.change()
x.identity # > 'bar'
x.key # > 'somekey'
```

What I want to keep acting on the returned object without reassigning x, e.g.:

```
x.change().identity # > 'blah'
x.identity # > *should* result in 'blah', not 'bar'
```

I gather I need some kind of container class that will delegate all method calls to a child variable, and reassign it. However, I can't figure out how. I imagine it works something like this:

```
x = SomeContainer(Foo, 'otherkey')
x.change().change()
x.key # > 'otherkey'
x.identity # > 'blah'
x.change()
x.identity # > 'foo'
```

Comment: I get the feeling that if you get this done, you'll then want to adapt it to change into arbitrary objects, and before you know it, you'll be making calls like `x.become(y)` and you won't even notice you've just reinvented variables.

Comment: Why would you not want to reassign? There should really be no reason to not to.

Comment: I can reassign, true, I'm just curious if there's an alternative. Once the webdriver navigates to a new page, the old page object is useless. Few/none of its commands will work, few/none of its elements exist, and it will fail validation.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the behaviour of some methods of your class, but don't intend to change the type of class then you might be interested in the State (Design) Pattern.

For example if you want change identity, depending on the current identity, you would have two different classes for every functionality.
In pseudo-code it works like this:

```
class BasicIdentity

    Identity identityA;
    Identity identityB;

    Identity currentIdentity;

    void PrintIdentity()
    {
        currentState.printIdentity()
    }

    void ChangeIdentity()
    {
         if currentIdentity == identityA
             currentIdentity = identityB
         else
             currentIdentity = identityA
    }
```